# Why do we require two memory barriers in a postbox data communication between two cores?

Tags: c, gcc, memory, arm

Here we have a code of postbox code for data communication between two ARM cores (directly referred from the [ARM Cortex A Series Programming Guide](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.den0013d/index.html)).

**Core A:**

```
STR R0, [Msg] @ write some new data into postbox
STR R1, [Flag] @ new data is ready to read
```

**Core B:**

```
Poll_loop:
LDR R1, [Flag]
CMP R1,#0 @ is the flag set yet?
BEQ Poll_loop
LDR R0, [Msg] @ read new data.
```

In order to enforce dependency, the document says that we need to insert not one, but two memory barriers, DMB, into the code.

**Core A:**

```
STR R0, [Msg] @ write some new data into postbox
DMB
STR R1, [Flag] @ new data is ready to read
```

**Core B:**

```
Poll_loop:
LDR R1, [Flag]
CMP R1,#0 @ is the flag set yet?
BEQ Poll_loop
DMB
LDR R0, [Msg] @ read new data.
```

I understand the first DMB in the Core A: it prevents compile reordering and also the memory access to [Msg] variable be observed by the system. Below is the definition of the DMB from the same document.

> > **Data Memory Barrier (DMB)**
> >     This instruction ensures that all memory
> >     accesses in program order before the barrier are observed in the
> >     system before any explicit memory accesses that appear in program
> >     order after the barrier. It does not affect the ordering of any other
> >     instructions executing on the core, or of instruction fetches.

However, I am not sure why the DMB in the Core B is used. In the document it says:

> Core B requires a DMB before the LDR R0, [Msg] to be sure that the
>   message is not read until the flag is set.

If the DMB in the Core A makes the store to the [Msg] be observed to the system, then we should not need the DMB in the second core. My guess is, the compiler might do a reordering of reading [Flag] and [Msg] in the Core B (though I do not understand why it should do this since the read on [Msg] is dependent on [Flag]).

If this is the case, a compile barrier (asm volatile("" ::: "memory) instead of DMB should be enough. Do I miss something here?

Comment: Don't know the memory model, but maybe core 2 is allowed to see writes in a different order from the one in which they occurred? Some Cortex-A's are out-of-order, so the load of the message could ahve run speculatively based on the branch predictor's output, independent of when the flag was fetched from memory.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both barriers are necessary, and do need to be `dmb`s - this is still about the hardware memory model, and nothing to do with compiler reordering.

Let's look at the writer on core A first:

```
STR R0, [Msg] @ write some new data into postbox
STR R1, [Flag] @ new data is ready to read
```

Since these are two independent stores to different addresses with no dependency between them, there is nothing to force core A to actually *issue* the stores in program order. The store to `Msg` could, say, linger in a part-filled write buffer whilst the store to `Flag` overtakes it and goes straight out to the memory system. Thus any observer other than core A could see the new value of `Flag`, without yet seeing the new value of `Msg`.

```
STR R0, [Msg] @ write some new data into postbox
DMB
STR R1, [Flag] @ new data is ready to read
```

Now, with the barrier, the store to `Flag` is not permitted to be visible before the store to `Msg`, because that would necessitate one or other store appearing to cross the barrier. Thus any external observer may either see both old values, the new `Msg` but the old `Flag`, or both new values. The previous case of seeing the new `Flag` but the old `Msg` can no longer occur.

OK, so the first barrier handles things getting *written* in the correct order, but there's also the matter of how they are *read*. Over on core B...

```
Poll_loop:
LDR R1, [Flag]
CMP R1,#0 @ is the flag set yet?
BEQ Poll_loop
LDR R0, [Msg] @ read new data.
```

Note that the branch to `Poll_loop` does not form a control dependency between the two loads; if you consider program order, the load of `Msg` is unconditional, and the value of `Flag` does not affect whether it is executed or not, only whether execution ever progresses to that part of the program at all. Therefore the code could equivalently be written thus:

```
Poll_loop:
LDR R1, [Flag]
LDR R0, [Msg] @ read data, just in case.
CMP R1,#0 @ is the flag set yet?
BEQ Poll_loop @ no? OK, throw away that data and read everything again.
... @ do stuff with R0, because Flag was set so it must be good data, right?
```

Start to see the problem? Even with the original code, core B is free to speculatively load `Msg` as soon as it reaches `Poll_loop`, so even if the stores from core A become visible in program order, things could still play out like this:

```
  core A   |  core B
-----------+-----------
           | load Msg
store Msg  |
store Flag |
           | load Flag
           | conclude that old Msg is valid
```

Thus you either need a barrier:

```
...
BEQ Poll_loop
DMB
LDR R0, [Msg] @ read new data.
```

or perhaps a fake address dependency:

```
...
BEQ Poll_loop
EOR R1, R1, R1
LDR R0, [Msg, R1] @ read new data.
```

To order the two loads against each other.

Comment: I wrote a C version of CoreA and Core B functions, Core B with no memory barrier, to see how the compiler generates the assembly. As far as I understand, the generated assembly has no control dependency or address dependency.

Comment: This is the assembly code without DMB:
Core B
180: e3003000  movw r3, #0
184: e3403000  movt r3, #0
188: e5933000  ldr r3, [r3]
18c: e3530000  cmp r3, #0
190: 1a000000  bne 198 <coreB+0x18>
194: eafffffe  b 194 <coreB+0x14>
     198: e3003000  movw r3, #0
     19c: e3403000  movt r3, #0
     1a0: e5930000  ldr r0, [r3]
     1a4: e12fff1e  bx lr

So what I understand from your post, this code is open to speculative reads for [Msg], r0 here, am I right?

Comment: Before C11, standard C had no notion of multiple threads at all, so you almost certainly won't get thread-safe code out of a compiler by default - given the C code `*msg = 3; *flag = true;` you can't even know what the _program order_ of the two stores is going to be once it's compiled and assembled. Even with C11, you'd need to use `<stdatomic.h>` stuff with suitable ordering constraints, rather than basic types, to end up generating correct code.

Comment: A control dependency is not enough, but a control dependency + ISB is, see §4.2 and §4.3 in "A Tutorial Introduction to the ARM and POWER Relaxed Memory Models": https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~pes20/ppc-supplemental/test7.pdf

Comment: @ninjalj Bah, you're quite right. Misreading the ARM ARM way past bedtime is one thing, managing to forget about branch speculation at the same time is quite another...

Answer (score 4):

First, you're kind of mixing up compiler barriers and memory barriers. Compiler barriers prevent the compiler from moving instructions across that barrier in the final assembly. OTOH, memory barriers instruct the *hardware* to obey a certain ordering. Since you're already presenting assembly code, your question is really about hardware memory barriers and there is no compiler involved here.

The reason why you need a (read) memory barrier in Core B is that the core may reorder the message reading instruction wherever it wants, since
no, there is no data dependency between the reading of the flag and the reading of the message, at least not in the code above: the only information needed for reading `Msg` is its address and this is known at each point in time. You might want to argue that there is a control dependency. However, control dependencies do not impose any ordering constraints on memory reads.